# AngularJS and getting ng-click to work on dynamically loaded html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wonder if i could get a little help here.  I am trying to build a small image gallery using AngularJS and Laravel.  So far everything is working out great. The problem I am having however is when I dynamically load one of my HTML files, the ng-click directive does not seem to work on the dynamic content.  I have looked into this and came across the $compile option, but I cannot for the life of me see how I can implement it.

Any one have any idea of what I need to do?  I have attached the code I am working with below:

**Controller Code**

```
App.controller('MyPhotos', function ($scope, $timeout, $http, $document, $modal, $log, $sce, $compile) {

$scope.loadAlbums = function () {

    $scope.loading = "<div class='text-center'><strong>...Loading...</strong></div>";
    $scope.isLoading = true;

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/my/photos/fetch/albums'
    }).success(function (data) {
        var htmlContent = $compile(data.albums)($scope);
        $scope.galleryContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.albums);
        $log.log(data.albums);
        $scope.isLoading = false;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        //$scope.progress = data;
        $scope.messages = 'There was a network error. Try again later.';
        //$log.error(data);
        $scope.isLoading = false;
    });
};
```

**Base Html Page**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><a href="#photos-all" class="photosList">Your Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#albums" class="albumsList" data-ng-click="loadAlbums();">Your Albums</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div ng-show="isLoading" class="text-center">
        <img src="{{ Theme::asset()->url('img/loading_balls.gif') }}" />
    </div>
    <div class="photoContainer" data-ng-bind-html="galleryContent">
        [[ galleryContent ]]
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Dynamically loaded HTML**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="" class="img-responsive"  />
    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Create album</a>
</div>
@foreach($albums as $album)
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="" class="img-responsive"  />
        <a href="#" data-ng-click="loadAlbum({{ $album->id }})" title="{!! $album->title !!}"
           data-album-id="{{ $album->id }}">{!! $album->title !!}
        </a>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

The data-ng-click directive is not working when the content is loaded dynamically.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you'll need to use `compile` for this. Both AngularJS and Laravel user the double bracket notation, which may be your problem. Clearly you are asking Laravel to obtain the `{{ $album->id }}` but it's going to be interpreted by AngularJS.  Perhaps a good way to get by this is to send an XHR request from AngularJS to Laravel, and then use javascript variables in the `ng-click`'s.

Comment: Try swapping out `data.albums` with `htmlContent` on the line `$scope.galleryContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.albums);`

Comment: swapping out data.albums with htmlContent returned the following error:

`Error: [$sce:itype] Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: html`

Comment: `ng-bind-html` is likely sanitizing the html.  It would be simpler to insert it yourself into the DOM using jQuery or plain old JavaScript.  After you do that, the `$compile(addedElement)($scope)` should work fine.

Comment: @SteveCampbell, that solved the problem.  Ended up just using jquery to display the html content and the ng-click now works...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this similarly in a much simpler way, using `ngInclude`:

```
<div class="photoContainer" ng-include="'/my/photos/fetch/albums'">
    <img src="{{ Theme::asset()->url('img/loading_balls.gif') }}" />
</div>
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude